# pandas filter column values by multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have df with multiple columns such as MLB, NBA, NHL, NFL, TESTNBA i would like to return a list where the columns have the string MLB or NBA in it. so like below:

```
df_check = ['MLB', 'NBA', 'TESTNBA']

value_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df_check in col]
```

The above fails with the following error:

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

Any way to filter columns by multiple values?

Comment: You are missing `'` for `NBA'`. change it to `df_check = ['MLB', 'NBA']` .

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to select 2 columns out of the whole dataframe right? In this case you can try: `df1 = df[['MLB','NBA']]`

Comment: or just `df[df_check]` but it will throw error if key is not present in df. It will work if keys are correct and expected in df.

Comment: yes, but let me adjust the question then. the string MLB and NBA might be in other columns so it is more of a like not an equal

Answer (score 1):

You may use [**`pandas.DataFrame.filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['MLB', 'NBA', 'NHL', 'NFL', 'TESTNBA'])    
df_check = ['MLB', 'NBA']
```

---

```
df.filter(regex='|'.join(df_check)).columns
```

```
Index(['MLB', 'NBA', 'TESTNBA'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I prefer keeping indexes as indexes, but either way, you can use the `tolist()` method of an index rather than using the `list` constructor

Comment: True, using `tolist()` is even better. It got my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator does not work in a vectorised fashion. With your logic you will need to use `any` with a generator expression:

```
value_cols = [col for col in df.columns if any(i in col for i in df_check)]
```

Better, you can use Boolean indexing with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['MLB1', 'NBA2', 'SOMEOTHERCOL', 'TESTNBA3', 'MLB4'])

df_check = ['MLB', 'NBA', 'TESTNBA']

value_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(df_check))]

Index(['MLB1', 'NBA2', 'TESTNBA3', 'MLB4'], dtype='object')
```